# Analysis Question Concerning The Axioms of Arithmetic and Order

Tags: real-analysis

Assume X is an ordered field, i.e. it is a set with binary operations "+" and "·" and a binary relation "≦" such that the axioms of arithmetic and the axioms of order are satisfied. Using only the axioms of arithmetic and order, show that if x,y ∈ X satisfy 0 ≦ x, 0 ≦ y and x ≦ y, then x·x ≦ y·y.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: That's equivalent to showing that $y^2 - x^2 = (y+x) (y-x)$ is greater than or equal to $0$.  (Try proving that with the axioms.)   So you just need to show that $y+x$ and $y-x$ are both greater than or equal to $0$.

Comment: Can you not write out the proof for me? Please

Answer (score 0):

you can invoke if $x \le y$ and $z \ge 0$, then $zx \le zy$ and the transitivity of the ordered fields.

try $xy$ and compare that to $xx$ and $yy$.